# See the proxy used in the browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, proxy, microsoft-edge

I use VPN browser extensions and therefore there is a different proxy on my browser than the whole system.

I want to see what exactly is the proxy information (port and address) used in my browser. How can I do this?

The browser I use is Edge and Chrome, and my operating system is Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log your network activity and find out your proxy setting within the `json` file. Just go to:

For Edge: `edge://net-export/`

For Chrome: `chrome://net-export/`

Comment: I would be grateful if you could point out an example of exactly which part of the log is related to the address and port of the proxy.
My log file was more than 7 thousand lines in a few seconds!

Comment: @MehrshadFarzaneh Of course. You can simply search for `proxySettings` in the file. Additionally, here's a net log viewer recommended by Chromium docs for you to see the information you need explicitly. https://netlog-viewer.appspot.com/#import